# DFT method for a sequence defined by recursion

Tags: fft, convolution, dft

I encountered the following interesting computational problem in the field of computational statistical mechanics.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yimd9uy5u0jrdj/dftpr.pdf

thank you :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: in this link:   http://www.docdroid.net/az0j/dftpr.pdf.html